# This is Exe file written in C#. How to work on Linux

Tags: c#

I made an exe file associated with the databases on c#. I did the following steps to work on Linux: but I'm not working

1. I wrote python code and call to exe file.
2. ./database.exe
3. Wine run

Тhe mistake is generally:

Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
err:systray:initialize_systray Could not create tray window

Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'HLR.Form1' from assembly 'HLR, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'HLR.Form1' from assembly 'HLR, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Help me guys.

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding about the capabilities of C#/.NET

Comment: Is it possible to work on Linux?

Comment: You can run C# code on Linux but it needs to be compiled for Linux (or .NET Standard). Also, you cannot use code that is based on WinForms/WPF which is what your code appears to be.

Comment: *.exe is basically executable only on Windows, you have to recompile it using Mono or run it inside a Virtual Machine (with Windows installed); other option would be to use .NET CORE, but it is limited only to UWP and ASP.NET core... Python won't make this work

Comment: Use mono to build your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the server from the .exe application itself, it is complicated but possible.

Once complicated, but ... you need to configure the WAS environment.

I think it's a good idea to use WCF to make it your own server. You can create a REST API definition from WCF and apply the WebRequest method from the client, Windows.

Links to read for your reference. It is called asp.net core, but as mentioned above, you can make the .exe program itself available as a server.

[Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Apache](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

The link below attached the visuals of the process of publishing from Windows to Linux.

It was a very simple example and a good resource.

[ASP.NET Core 1.0 + Apache on CentOS Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxF8FDaDFao&feature=youtu.be)

The last thing to note is that your .net core environment and your .net core environment must be the same.

For example, if you have created .net core 2.2, you should also get Linux with .net core 2.2.